# What distinguished the Republican Party of Liberia from the True Whig Party?

Tags: africa

What was the difference between the two parties? Wikipedia says that the Republican Party was made up primarily of Americo-Liberians who had mixed African and European ancestry. I assume the TWP was too, so that's not different. What is known about the Republican Party other than it was Americo-Liberian, had a couple of presidents, and that it ceased to exist early in Liberia's history?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible I misunderstood what the Wikipedia article said: according to a google book search, the True Whig Party was the political organisation of dark-skinned Americo-Liberians, who were believed to be of 100% African ancestry.

It seems the Republican Party was the party of light-skinned, apparently mixed race Americo-Liberians, who were called mullato people at the time.

The source is below, any other information would be welcome.

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rqioBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22republican+party%22+Liberia+%22true+whig+party%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZIUuVdS7CYvfywPTq4GIBg&ved=0CA0QuwUwAA#v=onepage&q=%22republican%20party%22%20Liberia%20%22true%20whig%20party%22&f=false